# ElasticSearch missing document exception

Tags: java, elasticsearch

A document is indexed in my ElasticSearch but it gives document source missing exception while update in elastic search

```
GET /ps_topcat_24/products/_search
{
 "query":{
     "match": {
        "_id": "957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d"
     }
 },
 "fields":["price"]
}
```

Response of ES :

```
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
  "total": 6,
  "successful": 6,
  "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "ps_topcat_24",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
           "price": [
              28.99
           ]
        }
     }
   ]
}
}
```

Which clearly shows the document is present.

But the update doesn't works

```
  POST/ps_topcat_24/products/957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d/_update
{
"doc":{
  "matching_id":"test-sourabh"
   }
}
```

It gives

```
{
 "error": {
   "root_cause": [
      {
         "type": "document_source_missing_exception",
         "reason": "[products][957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d]: document source missing",
         "shard": "2",
         "index": "ps_topcat_24"
      }
   ],
   "type": "document_source_missing_exception",
   "reason": "[products][957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d]: document source missing",
   "shard": "2",
   "index": "ps_topcat_24"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you get if you remove `"fields":["price"]` in your query?

Comment: Response remains the same only price is not shown in response

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you see exactly in your response? I'm guessing that you're not storing your document sources (i.e. _source is disabled in your mapping)

Comment: yes _source enabled is false . Does that effects the index of the document

Comment: Yes, that's the reason why you cannot run your partial update. You can try to re-index the full document (i.e. POST the full document to `/ps_topcat_24/products/957680208f55e89f407c6a479c9f3c9d`) instead of only updating one field.